# can not acces any element in object

Tags: php, xml, object, xml-parsing

I have an object( `$videopost` ) where I am not able to gte values form key with a score in the name.

I fetch my values that way:

```
$videopost->titel
```

What works fine.

this returns nothing:

```
 $videopost->vorschaubild-klein
```

But should return   `string(77) "http://www.neuwagen.de/images/screenshots/20130828_mercedes_cla_45_amg_nw.jpg"`

Why? Is the score in the key name the error?
How can I fix it?

this is my object

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4330 (18) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(3) "995"
  ["titel"]=>
  string(19) "Mercedes CLA 45 AMG"
  ["beschreibung"]=>
  string(217) "Mercedes hat sich selbst eine VerjÃ¼ngungskur verschrieben. Nicht nur das Make-Over der neuen der A-Klasse, sondern auch der vÃ¶llig neu entwickelte CLA sollen jÃ¼ngere Kunden zur Marke bringen. GroÃŸe Motoren locken."
  ["vorschaubild-klein"]=>
  string(77) "http://www.neuwagen.de/images/screenshots/20130828_mercedes_cla_45_amg_nw.jpg"
  ["vorschaubild-gross"]=>
  string(81) "http://www.neuwagen.de/images/screenshots_big/20130828_mercedes_cla_45_amg_nw.jpg"
  ["kategorie"]=>
  string(17) "Auto-Fahrberichte"
  ["modell"]=>
  string(3) "CLA"
  ["hersteller"]=>
  string(13) "Mercedes-Benz"
  ["datum"]=>
  string(19) "2013-10-04 14:40:11"
  ["geaendert"]=>
  string(19) "2013-10-04 12:44:17"
  ["dateiname"]=>
  string(35) "20130828_mercedes_cla_45_amg_nw.flv"
  ["hd-dateiname"]=>
  string(35) "20130828_mercedes_cla_45_amg_nw.f4v"
  ["mp4"]=>
  string(80) "http://cdn.connetv.de/cdn/auto-de/mp4/20130828_mercedes_cla_45_amg_nw_archiv.mp4"
  ["ipad"]=>
  string(79) "http://cdn.connetv.de/cdn/auto-de/ipad/20130828_mercedes_cla_45_amg_nw_ipad.m4v"
  ["iphone"]=>
  string(83) "http://cdn.connetv.de/cdn/auto-de/iphone/20130828_mercedes_cla_45_amg_nw_iphone.m4v"
  ["tags"]=>
  string(27) "mercedes-benz,cla,limousine"
  ["video-laenge"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["base_url"]=>
  string(41) "http://cdn.connetv.de/cdn/auto-de/archiv/"
}
```

Comment: `$videopost->{'vorschaubild-klein'}` Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `-` sign is treated as a substraction: `$videopost->vorschaubild` minus `klein` is actually evaluated. What is basically equivalent to `NULL - "klein"`.

To access it, use `$videopost->{'vorschaubild-klein'}`.